# Using Python, Batch Project output won't drop into feature dataset?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, batch

When attempting to batch project in ArcGIS 9.3 or 10 (using either arcpy or arcgisscripting), I cannot get my geoprocessing results to drop into the feature dataset that I specify.  The results instead are dropped in the root of the Geodatabase (*.mdb).

Here's an abbreviated version of what I have so far:

```
import arcgisscripting, os
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

#set date
dmy = datetime.now()
currentDate = str(dmy.month) + "-" + str(dmy.day) + "-" + str(dmy.year)

outputfolder = gp.getparameterastext(0) #where we're going to drop the gdb
citydata = gp.getparameterastext(1)

gp.workspace = outputfolder
projectedfolder = os.path.join(outputfolder, "projected")
gp.CreateFolder_management(*os.path.split(projectedfolder))
gdb = "Projected_Data_" + currentDate + ".mdb"

#set coordinate system
outputCS = gp.CreateObject("SpatialReference")
outputCS.createFromFile(os.path.join(gp.getinstallinfo()['InstallDir'], "Coordinate Systems\\Geographic Coordinate Systems\\North America\\NAD 1983.prj"))
transformation = ""

gp.AddMessage("Creating City feature dataset")
gp.CreateFeatureDataset(os.path.join(projectedfolder, gdb), "City", outputCS)

gp.AddMessage("Loading in City feature classes")
arcpy.BatchProject_management(citydata, os.path.join(projectedfolder, gdb, "City"), outputCS, "", transformation)
```

Obviously, the part I'm having trouble with is the Output Path in the last line.  I've also hard-coded the path to the "City" feature dataset, but still drops it in the root.  Any ideas?

(Cross-posted at ESRI Forums [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/39448-Using-Python-can-t-get-Batch-Project-outputs-to-save-in-a-feature-dataset?p=133624#post133624))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people have asked about this. At least one request (NIM013677) has been rejected with the status "as designed." The reason given is:

> Because when using the script version, the tool cannot know whether the target 
>   is a dataset or a feature class. It is designed to not support a feature dataset.

Std Disclaimer: I work at Esri, but not on the geoprocessing team (who made this decision).

Comment: Thanks for the info, mkennedy.  It seems odd that the script version of the tool is 'designed to not support a feature dataset' when it is a legitimate output workspace in virtually every other capacity

Comment: Update:  the ESRI forums cross-post has some interesting discussion about this issue for those interested.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in ArcGIS 10.1:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/39448-Using-Python-can-t-get-Batch-Project-outputs-to-save-in-a-feature-dataset?p=244841&viewfull=1#post244841

I tested it in the Python Window in ArcMap 10.1, it works :-)